# HTML loading commands on another page

Tags: javascript

I got requested to do a plugin that checks the comments of Planet Minecraft Every X Seconds and check if there are specific comments, then run a command if true
Therefor I must request the HTML from the Web, look which are the comments and add them to a Stringlist, Which worked fine so far
but then I need to load multiple pages, and that's where I'm stuck
I just can't load for example, page #2 of comments
http://m.imgur.com/pjYmlJo

Using Java script

Comment: Where's the **javascript**? You're not confusing **java** with **javascript**, are you? ;)  Also, **please don't** post links to images of text - just post the text. You can edit your question to include it. Also, where and why are you stuck there? You've not articulated what the problem actually is. Does the second page not have its own url (content is fetched with ajax) does your code fail on page2? And so on and so forth. Always try to keep in mind that we only know what you present to us. Mind reading costs extra and is generally unreliable between the days of Monday to Sunday (inclusive).

Comment: Oh, and welcome to SO. :) Feel free to have a look around the [help] to familiarize yourself with the workings of the site. :)